# If $A$ and $B$ are two are square matrix such that $AB=I$ , then which of following are necessarily not true

Tags: matrices

If $A$ and $B$ are two are square matrix such that $AB=I$ , then which of following are not necessarily not true

1. $BA=I$
2. $A=B^{-1}$
3. $B=A^{-1}$
4. $A^2=B$

$$AA^{-1}=I$$
$$BB^{-1}=I$$
I figured out that option $2,3$ are correct but how to check for $1$ and $4$

Comment: How could you verify 2. and 3. without proving 1. first?

Comment: How does that answer my question? How did you verify 2. and 3.?

Comment: @user218931 First line of my work show this

Comment: $A^{-1}$ is by definition the unique matrix such that $AA^{-1} = I$ *and* $A^{-1}A = I$, i. e. both equalities have to be satisfied. This means that you first have to verify 1. in order to conclude 2. and 3.

Comment: @user218931 Why it is necessary to first check 1 . I can put 2 and 3 in given equation and check whether it satisfy it not.

Answer (score 0):

1. note that A is full rank. for **any x**
   $$ABAx = Ax$$
   $$A(BAx-x) = 0$$
   that is
   $$BAx = x$$
   $$ (BA-I)x = 0$$
   $$BA = I$$
2. left multiply both side by A
   $$A^3 = AB = I$$ which is not always true.